# Calling a jQuery user defined function from Silverlight

Tags: c#, jquery, silverlight

I have this:

```
(function ($) {
  var myObj = {
    callMe: function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

and I would like to call the `callMe` function from Silverlight.

This does not seem to work:

```
ScriptObject jsObject = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("callMe");
jsObject.InvokeSelf('This is a message');
```

How would I go about exposing the callMe function so that I can Invoke it from Silverlight?

Answer: (since I don't have enough rep I have to answer here)

Tomalak,
you pointed me in the right direction!
It actually works both ways as long as you make it a property of the window object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {

        var myObj = {

            callThis:function(msg){
                console.log("Internal call:" + msg);
            }

        };
    window.myObj = myObj;

    window.callMe = function (msg) {
        console.log("External call:" + msg);
      }

    })(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.callMe("well, hello there...");
    window.myObj.callThis("... and hello you!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible with your code since `myObj` and its contents is *local* to your JavaScript function.

Make it a property of the `window` object instead.

```
(function ($) {
  window.callMe = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That does not work. I get 'Unexpected token ('
        (function ($) {
         window.callMe: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
          }

        })(jQuery);

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.callMe("test");
    </script>

Comment: @Jonah: Sorry, my bad. Fixed, try again.

Comment: Tomalak: I've given the answer as an edit in my question. You'll be getting your points! Thanks!

Comment: @Jonah Of course it works both ways as long as you make it a property of the window object. That's the whole point. ;)